# Is it possible to customize the font and appearance of a UIAlertController in the new XCode w/ iOS8?

Tags: swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

I'm wondering if it's possible to customize in app alerts with the UIAlertController. I haven't seen anything that explicitly says that you can. Does anyone know of a way I can add a custom appearance, particularly with fonts on these alerts?

Comment: Seems related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497218/change-the-font-of-uialertaction-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with appearanceWhenContainedIn. To set up background color, here's an example:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Or tint color:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: What about for the font?