# Change the Font of UIAlertAction in Swift

Tags: fonts, uialertaction

Changing the font for the message and title of a UIAlertViewController object has already been answered here: [How to change font size and color of UIAlertAction in UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382034/how-to-change-font-size-and-color-of-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller/29382203#29382203).

But I want to know how to change the font on the title of UIAlertAction (iOS8+) using Swift. Unfortunately, a UIAlertAction instance does not have an attribute called "attributedTitle" just like an UIAlertController.

The code I want to extend to change the font is below:

```
let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: .Default, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(alertAction)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357066/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-font-and-appearance-of-a-uialertcontroller-in-th