# Is it possible to set custom font & size for NSString?

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, ios9, uialertaction

I'm working with Swift in iOS 9. I want to customize the font for a `UIAlertAction`. I searched these questions for a Swift answer:

[Change the Font of UIAlertAction in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497218/change-the-font-of-uialertaction-in-swift)

[Is it possible to customize the font and appearance of a UIAlertController in the new XCode w/ iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357066/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-font-and-appearance-of-a-uialertcontroller-in-th)

And this question for an Objective-C answer:
[UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

But there was no solution for customizing the font for a `UIAlertAction`.

I believe the problem is that a `UIAlertAction` uses an `NSString` for its `title` property. [See demo project on Github.](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/3dde29deb7000cfac59d3e5473a71557123f29ea/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertAction.h)

I would like to create a string like so:

```
let originalString: String = "OK"
let myString: NSString = originalString as NSString
```

And then customize the string's font & size. Then after adding my actions to the alert controller, assign the string to my actions using key-value coding:

```
alertController!.actions[0].setValue(myString, forKey: "title")
```

But as far as I can tell, there is no way to set a custom font and size for an `NSString`. If it used a `UILabel` instead, then it would be easy to customize the font. But I seem to be stuck with the limitations of strings. Does anyone know a way to assign a custom font & size to a string, or am I correct in believing there is no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `NSAttributedString` (or its mutable counterpart, `NSMutableAttributedString`) to make a string with custom info. As the constructor takes an `NSString` (or `String` in Swift), it will not take an `NSAttributedString` (`NSAttributedString` isn't a subclass of `NSString`.).

You could fudge the Swift compiler into passing an `NSAttributedString` using `unsafeBitCast`, but `UIAlertAction` may not like it.

---

Looking at [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color), it seems that you can set it using KVO. The code for doing of so is similar:

```
var alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Dont care what goes here, since we're about to change below", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
let hogan = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!")
hogan.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50), range: NSMakeRange(24, 11))

alertVC.setValue(hogan, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

Comment: Looks like you were right about not liking the fudge. I tried this: `let hogan = NSAttributedString(string: "Leg Drop", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 22)!])` `let unsafeHogan : NSString = unsafeBitCast(hogan, NSString.self)`
Then added it: `alertController!.actions[0].setValue(unsafeHogan, forKey: "title")`
It compiled OK but threw a runtime error:
_Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0e87accf0_ 
Guess you can't fool it!